# Vijual tree graphs

Tags: graphics, clojure, tree

In trying to use the draw-tree function from vijual I have run into some issues. First, I'm unsure if I am using the right namespace`(:require vijual :reload)`, since I have not been able to draw any trees. I have also tried `(:require vijual.graphical)` but that was not recognized. This has led to `draw-tree` not being recognized, i.e. CompilerException Unable to resolve symbol.

The nodes of the trees should correspond to n-tuples and in the case below 3-tuples. The inputs have looked like

```
(def foo (draw-tree [[:vec (9/2 6 13/2) [[[:vec (1 2 3)] [:vec (2 3 4)]] [:vec (3 4 5)]] [:vec (7 9 9)]]]))
```

which corresponds to the tree

```
{:vec (9/2 6 13/2)
 :right {:vec [7 9 9]},
 :left  {:right {:vec [3 4 5]}, 
         :left  {:vec [1 2 3]}, 
         :vec (2 3 4)}}
```

The dependency I have been using is `[org.clojars.overtone/vijual "0.2.1"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are at a repl, this should work:

```
(use 'vijual)
(def foo (draw-tree ....
```

use refers another namespaces symbols into your current namespace so you can call them without qualifying them. require loads the namespace but would require you to reference symbols with it:

```
(require 'vijual)
(def foo (vijual/draw-tree ...
```

When I did this the function was invoked, but still had errors. In particular, you have `(9/2 6 13/2)` etc - this will attempt to invoke 9/2 as a function. I don't quite understand exactly what you are shooting for (in particular with the map) but this does a start of something:

```
(def foo (draw-tree [[:vec [9/2] [6] [13/2]] ]))
```